# How can I temporarily finish a basement without actually finishing it?

Tags: basement-refinishing

I just bought a brand new townhouse and had plans to immediately finish the basement. I would like to turn it into the media and tv area, as the living room on the main floor is not big enough for the whole family.

The problem is, the builder has stated in the warranty that we can't finish the basement for the first two years. We have to wait until the foundation settles. Otherwise, we void the structural damage warranty.

Doe anyone have some ideas on what we could do?

Comment: What does "finish" mean in this case?

Comment: I have never heard such a thing. Finish work is not considered structural. That's like saying you can't move in because the foundation will take years to stabilize. Since it is new construction I would want to see if the basement is dry prior to finish work and this may be there real reason for the 2 years. You finish the basement and the walls leak and ruin the finish work they have a liability issue.

Comment: Builder probably wants easy access to the foundation, etc., should something go wrong that is under warranty. Easier on both parties.

Answer (score 6):

You could pin up several runs of **[Backdrop Drapes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071L8FR1F)** along the walls. They come in many colors and are less than $40 for a 10' wall span. You could cut out around the windows and even hang a temporary blind. If you already have all of the electrical installed it would be easy to pull some short extension cords underneath or in between the curtains for TV's. 
[image: Backdrop Drapes]
Some cheap **[indoor/outdoor carpet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMASTER-Elevations-Color-Sky-Grey-Ribbed-Texture-Indoor-Outdoor-12-ft-Carpet-7PD5N660144H/203240740?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CVF%7CD23%7C23-2_CARPETING%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000033393850%7C58700004413536484%7C92700037075139627&gclid=CjwKCAiA4t_iBRApEiwAn-vt-_uamJ_fJm8LDKHRfCH15psDA1NkLR6gqnX7BLoqPGO9YzmOaj6NOBoCsjkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)** for the floors would be cozy if you threw down some temporary rugs. You could use a few screws and pin it to the bottom plate to prevent too much sliding.
[image]